# Dose docker container cause slow Disk/OS performance

Tags: hard-drive, performance, docker, redhat-enterprise-linux

We have 3 servers , that installed with  RHEL 7.6 version

The machines are DELL physical machines with spec as `RAM = 64G` and `CPU = 16`

We prepare to install the services - `kafka/zookeeper/schema registry` on all machines , but each service is based on docker container

So we are intend to install docker on all kafka machines

And finally each kafka machine will contain docker service and 3 docker containers per machine

**The question is** – dose docker containers have negative impact when all contraries are part of the OS disk?

Other suggestion is to add additional disk on each machine and allocate the docker containers on the addition disk ?

So what is the best practice here ,

1. Locate the docker containers on the OS disk
2. Locate the docker containers on additional disk ( not the OS disk )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove docker from the question since it's assembling other Linux features to create containers. Look at the graph driver to assess the container filesystem overhead. That's likely overlay2. Once the file has been opened for writing and the copy-on-write has been performed, that performance is likely indistinguishable from the underlying filesystem. However if you modify lots of files from the parent image layers, expect lots of copy-on-writes which will result in some overhead.

Typically, you don't write to the container filesystem with data, rather that is mounted as a volume, and the performance of that is directly related to the source of that volume. NFS mounts will have NFS performance. A bind mount to a host directory will have the performance of that underlying host filesystem.

Whether you separate the docker filesystem from the OS disk is often not a performance question, but rather a disk space question. Containers can grow, especially if you do not limit the log file size. And images have a way of multiplying if you pull new versions without cleaning up old tags of images. If you fill the filesystem unexpectedly with docker, it's much easier to recover if that isn't the root filesystem too.